# How to consume REST API with Angular2?

Tags: javascript, rest, angular, typescript

This is my demo code:

**products.service.ts**

```
getProducts(){
 this.headers = new Headers();
 this.headers.append("Content-Type", 'application/json');
 this.headers.append("Authorization", 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('id_token'));
 return this.http.get('http://mydomain.azurewebsites.net/api/products',{headers:headers}).map(res => res.json().data);
}
```

**products.component.ts**

```
constructor(private productsService: ProductsService) { }

ngOnInit() {
 this.productsService.getProducts().subscribe((res) => {
    console.log(res); 
 });
}
```

Is it nescessary to import something in the `ngModule` decorator to consume a REST API or my code is wrong? I can get the desired data with Postman Chrome Extension but not with Angular 2 code.

I hope to have explained my problem well.

***Update***

These are the errors i get:

[image]

Comment: What do you get instead of the data you're expecting?  An error?  Nothing at all?

Comment: looks like you got 404 but don't have handler in _subscribe_ for error.

Comment: Can you inspect the network tab in developer window, to see that the actual request is sent to which URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for making you waste your time.

This was the problem:

**app.module.ts**

```
providers: [
    ProductsService,
    // { provide: XHRBackend, useClass: InMemoryBackendService }, // in-mem server
    // { provide: SEED_DATA,  useClass: InMemoryDataService }     // in-mem server data
  ]
```

After commenting the `in-mem server` and and the `in-mem server data` the problem dissapeared.

Answer (score 2):

You're not setting the headers in the request.  You declare the `Headers` object but you don't actually do anything with it.

You need to set them in the `get` function like this:

```
return this.http
           .get('http://mydomain.azurewebsites.net/api/products', { headers: headers })
           .map(res => res.json().data);
```

Comment: Sorry, actually i had set the headers but copied and pasted wrong. Thanks anyway for the attention.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you use **ngx-rest-ex**: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-rest-ex

```
npm i -S ngx-rest-ex
```

It's convenient, you just need to specify the corresponding decorator on top of the method and the return type, it will replace your method body. The return type can be either `Promise` or `Observable` depending on the HTTP METHOD annotation that you specified.

My demo code for your case:

```
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { BaseUrl, GET, RESTClient } from 'ngx-rest-ex';

import { Product } from './models';


@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
@BaseUrl('http://mydomain.azurewebsites.net/api/')
export class ApiService extends RESTClient {

    constructor(injector: Injector) { super(injector); }

    protected getDefaultHeaders() {
        return {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('id_token')
        };
    }

    @GET('products')
    getProducts(): Promise<Product[]> {
        return;
    }
}
```